# Как убрать ошибки связанные с функциями WP в VSC?

Tags: wordpress, visual-studio-code

Как убрать подобные ошибки (в окне Problems) в Visual Studio Code? (немного раздражают!)
Я так понимаю надо установить какое-то расширение, но не понимаю какое.

Undefined function 'language_attributes'. intelephense(1010),
Undefined function 'bloginfo', intelephense(1010)
Undefined function 'wp_head' intelephense(1010)
Undefined function 'is_page'. intelephense(1010)

и т.д. связанные с функциями WP...

Пробовал разные расширения из репозитория VSC связанные с WP - не помогло!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60332075/6817117

Comment: Ну а вообще, всё это костыли. Все функции придётся добавлять вручную, для ядра и плагинов. Используйте PhpStorm, там всё определяется автоматически.

Comment: Спасибо KAGG Design за коммент. Я в принципе так и догадывался о таком развитии событий. Ок.